# Cannot start activity - activity destroy timeout for historyrecord

Tags: android

Any ideas what could be causing the message from ActivityManager, "Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord" when attempting to end an activity. This prevents the activity from restarting.

I'm stuck. Don't even have an idea where to look.

Comment: Could you define "attempting to end an activity"? Also, could you define "prevents the activity from restarting"?

Comment: I am also stuck but I hope [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) will help.

Comment: I too came around with the same issue today. With little trial and error, I found that the the layout file wasn't attached to the Activity and hence the error. :) Silly me. :)

Answer (score 1):

For me this was a permissions issue. I recommend checking the full logcat output.

Comment: Good catch. That was it.

Answer (score 0):

on older APIs, this can also be caused on context or view leaks. Worth investigating. In my case, I put log statements onCreate and onDestroy for my fragments, then, in an instrumentation test, repeatedly added, then removed the fragment from view. That helped to isolate the problem area

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem. What I've done is I lunched my app with debugger and I saw it stopped somewhere in system classes. But in local variables I could see NullPointerException.

Then I figured out that in a constructor of one of my classes I didn't initialise variable.

Just double check you constructors.